# DNSUnlocker ads in Firefox

Tags: firefox, dns, virus-removal

I'm getting bombarded with ads in my browser "Brought to you by DNSUnlocker".

This seems to only be effecting one site, and only in Firefox. The site however is a local development version of a site I'm building. If I use a different browser, or a I use "Private Browsing" in Firefox it doesn't seem to happen. I'm fairly sure the source for my site is not corrupted. I'm fairly sure this is just a DNS, or Firefox issue.

I'm using google public DNS, and the settings still seem to be correct. I've checked my hosts file, and this is also correct.

Any idea where this could be coming from?

Update: I've cleared my cache, and history in Firefox and this appears to have fixed it. However I'm still confused as to how this could have happened, or if this means my computer has been compromised in some more insidious way.

This may be related. When the popup ads were occurring, I was tethered through my 4g mobile phone. I'm now connected through my normal WiFi.

Comment: How can we check what causes it if we can't see the source code, access the site or at least see the generated HTML?

Comment: I checked the source code with curl, and there was nothing coming through in that. If something was being injected, it was happening just in the browser, and when this was occurring I wasn't able to get to the source in Firefox as the browser became unresponsive, dealing with thousands of popup requests.

Comment: I'm, just hoping that someone may have experience with DNSUnlocker, and how it functions. Since clearing the browser cache the issue has stopped so I can't investigate further.

Comment: If you do have DNSUnlocker, you should try following the instructions at http://howtoremove.guide/dns-unlocker-removal/

Comment: Thanks @JuliePelletier I've checked all the locations suggested, and found nothing obviously suspicious. It's very strange. I've turned off all of the Firefox plugins anyway, just to be safe.

Comment: You should at the very least test the site from another computer with the same OS and browser to make sure where the problem is located.